# rspec: Put request define url source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following test:

```
it "should generate invoice on reconnect finish after cycle_date" do
 params = {
   :id => @reconnect.id,
   :state => "Finish",
   :install => {
     :notes => "blah"
   }
 }
 put :update, params
 @reconnect.reload
 expect(@reconnect.customer.invoices.count).to eq 1
 expect(@reconnect.state). to eq "completed"
end
```

but I need for the line `put :update, params`to allow me to specify which url it's coming from because in my route:

```
resources :installs, :except => [:index, :show], :controller => "appointments" do
collection do
  get ':id/admin_edit', to: 'appointments#admin_edit', as: :edit_admin
end
  end

resources :reconnects, :except => :index, :controller => "appointments" do
    collection do
      get ':id/schedule_reconnect/:address_id', to: 'reconnects#schedule_reconnect', as: :schedule
      get 'reconnect_appointment', to: 'reconnects#reconnect_appointment'
      post 'submit_reconnect', to: 'reconnects#submit_reconnect', as: :submit_reconnect
      post 'complete_reconnect', to: 'reconnects#complete_reconnect', as: :complete_reconnect
      get ':id/admin_edit', to: 'appointments#admin_edit', as: :edit_admin
    end
  end
```

and in the controller:

```
def classify_path
    @appointment_type = self.request.path.split("/")[1]
    @appointment_type_singular = @appointment_type.chomp("s")
    @appointment_type_class = @appointment_type.classify.constantize
  end
```

So for my test I need to specify if its an "install" or a "reconnect" in the test.

Comment: I think the way you've drawn your routes is flawed -- how is the controller supposed to know the difference between the `reconnects` and the `installs` ? Both are pointing to the same methods on the same controller.

Comment: see the edit to my post to include a missing method

Comment: Note: not an answer... just thought you might want to know. Instead of `@appointment_type_singular = @appointment_type.chomp("s")` I'd use `@appointment_type_singular = @appointment_type.singularize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `use_route` helper in your rspec tests to achieve this:

```rb
params = {
  use_route: 'reconnects',
  id:        @reconnect.id,
  state:     'Finish',
  reconnect: { notes: 'blah' }
}

put :update, params
```

Answer (score 0):

oolong's answer was the closest, but the solution is:

```
params = {
  :use_route => 'reconnects',
  :id => @reconnect.id,
  :state => "Finish",
  :reconnect => {
    :notes => "blah"
  }
}
put :update, params
```

Comment: Edited my answer to fix the syntax problem you were likely experiencing